# Searching through objects with multiple criteria

Tags: java, search, parameters, criteria

So, here's my problem. I have objects like this

```
public class FooClass{
    private int fooInt;
    private String fooString, fooString_2;
}
```

and I have to search through them, differentiating them by either one of their parameters. Also, I am required to store them as binary files (`ObjectOutputStream` etc). So far I thought of using multiple `ArrayList`,or multiple `HashMap` but the problem with the latter would be that I need to perform partial String match, (`beginsWith`), so `HashMap` would be pretty useless I think.. Anyway having multiple lists of the same objects seems horrible in terms of implementations, and at this point I'm really stuck and out of ideas. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why don't you think that `HashMap` would work?

Comment: have you tried to use a text search engine library like [Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/core/)?

Comment: @gobernador How could `HashMap` work with partial string match? I would have to check all the keys, since `HashMap` methods work by retrieving values based on the exact associated key.. at least afaik! @Luiggi thank you very mych for the suggestion, I will look into it! I hope it helps :)

Comment: You would have to use `Map.keySet().iterator()`. I suppose if you expect a gigantic map, then it wouldn't be exactly what you want, but otherwise I don't see why it wouldn't work

Comment: @gobernador sorry I didn't mean that it wouldn't work, it's just that iterating through all objects isn't the best thing in terms of speed. I wonder if it would be better using arraylist for partial binary search AND hash map for exact match?

Comment: `HashMap` will work great for exact match, but you're right, an `ArrayList` would probably be faster to do a partial match search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this article: [Use search engine technology for object persistence](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-01-2005/jw-0103-search.html?page=2) (I haven't read it entirely) but I think it's the solution you are looking for. The solution is base on Lucene.

If you will decide to use Lucene, then you should look at those [tutorials](http://www.lucenetutorial.com/index.html). Part of this tutorials also talks about [Basic Concepts](http://www.lucenetutorial.com/basic-concepts.html) which will help you to decide whether this solution works for you.

If you want your data to be represented as Java objects (I think it's a solution you are really looking for), it would be better to use [Compass](http://compass-project.org/) (built on top of Lucene). It supports automatic marshalling, which means that Compass extract the required property from the Object model at run-time and inserts the required meta-data into the Search Engine index.. Take a look at the **OSEM - Object/Search Engine Mapping** in the [Compass reference](http://www.compass-project.org/docs/2.2.0/reference/pdf/compass-reference.pdf).